# Java - variable identifier for class

Tags: java

So i have the following code:

```
public static String currentLevel = "Level_1_1";
public boolean isCollingWithBlock(Point pt1, Point pt2){
    for(int x=(int)(this.x/Tile.tileSize);x<(int)(this.x/Tile.tileSize + 3);x++){
        for(int y=(int) (this.y/Tile.tileSize);y<(int)(this.y/Tile.tileSize + 3);y++){
            if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < Component.Level_1_1.block.length && y < Component.Level_1_1.block[0].length){

                // blocks
                if(Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].id != Tile.air && Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].id != Tile.death && Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].id != Tile.win){
                    if(Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].contains(pt1) || Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].contains(pt2)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                if(Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].id == Tile.death){
                    if(Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].contains(pt1) || Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].contains(pt2)){
                        alive = false;
                        deathText = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                if(Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].id == Tile.win){
                    if(Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].contains(pt1) || Component.Level_1_1.block[x][y].contains(pt2)){
                        win = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

This is on my Character class to see if there is collision wiht a block from the level class (in this case level 1_1)

So ofcause i dont only want 1 level, i want more then 1 level so i wish the:

```
Component.Level_1_1
```

To be a variable:

My current level is explained in the following way:

```
public static String currentLevel = "Level_1_1";
```

In the character class.
I tried to do the following:

```
Component.(currentLevel)
```

But it did not work.
What can i do the make the following work?

EDIT:
OK some didnt understand what i wanted to do..
What i want is in the isCollingWithBlock, to make Component.Level_1_1.block a variable.
because im going to have levels like: Component.Level_1_2.block, Component.Level_1_3.block etc. 
this should be decided by my: public static String currentLevel = "Level_1_1";

Comment: Where is the code of Character class?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you basically have a design flaw, if you have classes Level_1_1, Level_1_2 etc, each with static variables. Think in a more object oriented way, with *instances* representing the levels.

Comment: i have updated the post. Can someone please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon Skeet said in comments, you should not have a class by level. Instead, use a single class `Level` representing a level, and create one instance of that class by level.

Comment: hmm... how would i do that?

Comment: @user1953489 you don't know how to create an instance of a class?

Comment: @WilQu Maybe if you would give some examples for the object structure, he could get some idea what we mean...

Comment: @GaborSch yes, but maybe he can get some idea on his own :)